# Deny bots to download my files

Tags: download, bandwidth, bots

I have a asp.net download page which send a file to client but I want to deny robots download this file because the file is large and as I can see from the records a bot downloads this file about 20 times. This is slowing down the server and causes bandwidth consumption.

I coded this page to count downloads and detect .net framework of the client so I can post a setup file containing .net framework or not.

I need somehow to deny Google and other bots to reach this page.

My download link is like download.aspx?pack=msp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, add a robots.txt file to your site. It should contain a list of rules (suggestions really) how spiders should behave.

Check out [this](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/robots.htm) article for more info. Also for kicks, [this](http://www.google.com/robots.txt) is the robot.txt file used by Google.

Answer (score 4):

You want a [robots.txt file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt). For example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /download.aspx
```

This doesn't forcibly block search engines, but most (including Google) will check for a robots.txt file and follow its instructions

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer, as noted by the other two people, is to created a robots.txt file to make *well-behaved* robots not download things.

However, it is important to know that not all robots are well-behaved, and that robots.txt is only advisory.  If you have pages which are not publicly linked, do not list them in robots.txt to "protect" them as some particularly badly-behaved robots actually scan the file to see what interesting URLs there may be that they don't already know about.

Answer (score 3):

In lieu of a robots.txt file, where it isn't possible you can decorate your pages with a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag.

- Again, as Donnie mentioned, this is
  just a recommendation for bots and
  there is no requirement to follow it.
- Implement a CAPTCHA method that
  provides a login mechanism to allow
  desirable users to access a protected
  folder where you keep your biggest
  files.
- Instead of providing direct links to
  content that is easily parsed by
  bots, **use Javascript on your download link** to redirect your
  users.  Many bots won't execute
  javascript, though bot obfuscation is
  often a moving target.